# What is "xART Remote Storage Daemon" in macOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

I found in my newly installed macOS system there is a service running on port 61500 and the process command is `/usr/libexec/xartstorageremoted`

I issued `man xartstorageremoted` and found the manual of this deamon. After reading it I still don't understand what is this deamon used for. I searched Google and there is nearly nothing about it. Does anyone know something about it? What it used for in a common user's perspective?

> The xartstorageremoted executable is a daemon intended to listen for save/fetch requests from the CoProcessor. This daemon is required for multi-partitions and multi-users support.
>
> xartstorageremoted must not be unloaded and should only be run via launchd when a request must be handled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the MacBook's with Touch Bar there is a new processor, Apple’s T1 processor.

The deamon `xartstorageremoted` talks with the T1 processor.

[Secure Enclave](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/secure-enclave-overview-sec59b0b31ff/web) is part of it meaning it’s tied explicitly to the Touch Bar and Touch ID. It’s also in charge of your webcam, a small but important difference.

Answer (score 7):

Nice. Something poorly documented, yet in charge of a webcam and Touch ID, opens a global listener socket under the root account.

```
root# lsof -i tcp

xartstora 13594      root    3u  IPv4 0x30c82343150af2cf      0t0  TCP *:61500 (LISTEN)
xartstora 13594      root    4u  IPv6 0x30c82343150af2cf      0t0  TCP *:61500 (LISTEN)
```

I'd understand if it opened a UNIX domain socket or bound to 127.0.0.1 but binding to 0.0.0.0 (*) is a security problem from my point of view.

Comment: Well now I'm curious as to  what this is...

Comment: Found out what it is yet?